# Will big android Activity wiriting cause any effect to my App

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-intent

I'm making my first official application to put on the market and i was wondering would over 120 new activities  be too many if I'm only using them to pull text? If so is there a way I could turn  MysecondActivity to a giant if or switch statement?
This is the example I found in a book I changed up case 0: I'm going to change up the rest be similar to case 0 once i get an answer.

Thank you in advance and sorry for messy code and writing

```
         AndroidManifest.xml

       <activity android:name=".MySecondActivity" />

        ListActivityExample.java
        import android.app.ListActivity;
        import android.app.SearchManager;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

    public class ListActivityExample extends ListActivity{
        static final String[] ACTIVITY_CHOICES = new String[] {
            "Open new Actvity",
            "Open Contacts",
            "Open Phone Dialer Example",
            "Search Google Example",
            "Start Voice Command"
        };
        final String searchTerms = "superman";

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ACTIVITY_CHOICES));
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3){
                switch(arg2) {
                 case 0: //opens new screen
                {Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivityExample.this,MySecondActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        break;}
                    case 1: //opens phone dialer and fills in the given number
                        {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/")));
                        break;}
                    case 2:            
                        {
                          startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("tel:12125551212")));
                         break;}
                    case 3: //
                        {
                        Intent intent1= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                        intent1.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, searchTerms);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;}
                    case 4: // 
                        {startActivity(new
                                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND));
                        break;}
                        default: break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        }


    MySecondActivity.java

    mport android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MySecondActivity extends Activity {
         @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             TextView tv = new TextView(this);
             tv.setText("text here");
             setContentView(tv);
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing I can see about this code that will cause an issue with a large Activity stack.  Start as many Activities as you like, as long as they aren't all stacked together at the same time.  With this code you are starting a new Activity as a result of tapping an item in the list, but the user must finish the new Activity (press back) when returning to your list to start something else, so they aren't all in memory at once.

Does that help?  Or did I misunderstand your question?